# Pygame Python crash course bullets not firing page 253 AttributeError: 'AlienInvasion' object has no attribute 'settingsbullets_allowed'

Tags: python, pygame

Python Pygame issue in Alien Invasion game causing the game to keep crashing when trying to fire bullets. I just finished chapter 12 in Python Crash Course, and my ship wont fire bullets and the game crashed when pressing spacebar to fire bullets. Any help I can get in solving this issue is much appreciated. Attribute error is listed in title.

alien_invasion.py

```
import sys
import pygame

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
from bullet import Bullet 

class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manange game assests and behavior."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        self.ship = Ship(self)
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()

        #Set the background color.
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self.ship.update()
            self._update_bullets()
            self._update_screen()

            # Get rid of bullets that have disappeared.
            for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
                if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
                    self.bullets.remove(bullet)
                #print(len(self.bullets))    

            # Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
            self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
            self.ship.blitme()

            # Make the most recently drawn screen availible.
            pygame.display.flip()    

    def _check_events(self):
        """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_events(event)

                #Move th ship to the right
                self.ship.rect.x += 1  

    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        """Respond to keypresses."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            self._fire_bullet()            



    def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
        """Responds to releases.""" 
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = False



    def _fire_bullet(self):
        """Create a new bullet and add it to the new bullets group."""
        if len(self.bullets) < self.settingsbullets_allowed:
            new_bullet = Bullet(self)
            self.bullets.add(new_bullet)




    def _update_bullets(self):
        """Update position of bullets and get rid of old bullets."""
        # Update bullet positions.
        self.bullets.update()

        # Get rid of bullets that have disappeared.
        for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
            if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
                self.bullets.remove(bullet)




    def _update_screen(self):
        """Update images on the screen, and flip to the new screen."""
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()
        for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            bullet.draw_bullet()            



        # Make the most recently drawn screen availible.
        #pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Make a game instance, and run the game.
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

bullet.py

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite 

class Bullet(Sprite):
    """A class to manage bullets fired from a ship"""

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Create a bullet object at the ship's current position."""
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.color = self.settings.bullet_color

        # Create a bullet rect at (0, 0) and then set correct position.
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.settings.bullet_width, 
            self.settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect.mid_top = ai_game.ship.rect.mid_top


        # Store the bullet's position at a decimal value.
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)


    def update(self):
        """Move the bullet up the screen."""
        # Update the decimal position of the bullet.
        self.y -= self.settings.bullet_speed
        # Update the rect position
        self.rect.y = self.y    

    def draw_bullet(self):
        """Draw the bullet to the screen."""
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

settings.py

```
class Settings:
    """A Class to store all settings for Alien Invasion."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initializing the game's settings."""
        #Screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

        #Ship settings
        self.ship_speed = 1.5

        #Bullet settings
        self.bullet_speed = 1.0 
        self.bullet_width = 3
        self.bullet_height = 15 
        self.bullet_color = (60, 60, 60)
        self.bullets_allowed = 3
```

ship.py

```
import pygame

class Ship:
    """A class to manage the ship."""

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initialize the ship and set its starting position."""
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        #Load the ship and imagine its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images_ai/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        #Start each new ship at the bottom of the screen.
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

        #Store a decimal value for the ship's horizontal position.
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)

        # Movement flags
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False

    def update(self):
        """Update the ship's position based on movement flags."""
        # Update the ship's x value, not the rect.
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.x += self.settings.ship_speed 
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.x -= self.settings.ship_speed

        # Update rect object from self.x.
        self.rect.x = self.x        

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the ship at its current location."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Comment: Typo `self.settingsbullets_allowed` -> `self.settings.bullets_allowed`

Comment: There's numerous other errors in the code. Look back over the tutorial and check for mistakes.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the help, I fixed the typos and now I'll have to figure out why the ship still wont fire bullets but at least now it doesn't crash when i press spacebar.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by a typo. `self.settingsbullets_allowed` has to be `self.settings.bullets_allowe`